# Magento 1.8.1 Bundled Product Error

Tags: php, html, magento

First time I have setup a Bundled product. I get this error

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method Mage_Bundle_Model_Product_Price::getBasePrice() in /chroot/home/acuitysp/acuity-sports.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Bundle/Model/Product/Price.php on line 125

[Here is the Error on page](https://www.acuity-sports.com/default/sales-clearance-specials/backyard-batting-cage-package.html)

I have looked around, but I don't see any similar errors.